# Quantlib FloatingRateBond cashflow computation

Tags: c++, floating, forward, rate, quantlib

Looking at the Bond.cpp example: http://quantlib.org/reference/_bonds_8cpp-example.html it looks like `depoSwapTermStructure` and `liborTermStructure` are exactly the same curve. However, for the floating rate bond it seems that the FloatingRateBond class is computing the coupon rates, and therefore the cashflows, for the floatingRateBond instance by computing the forward rates and then adding the spread to it (which sounds right to me).

Is this correct or is it the case for this example that the forecasted cashflows are being computed by taking the spot curve only and adding the spread to obtain the forecasted coupon rates?

Comment: In my answer below, I've tried to explain what happens in the example. However, I'm not really sure of the difference between the two alternatives you're listing. What's the difference between "computing the forward rates and then adding the spread" and "taking the spot curve only and adding the spread"? How would you compute the forward rates if not on the spot curve?

Comment: It is done using the spot curve, I agree. So are you saying that somewhere along the way the forward rates are computed to compute the cash flows, is that right? If so, where are these computations of the forward rates done? Could you please point me towards it? I don't see how the forward rates are computed or where exactly is this done

Answer (score 1):

There are two different kind of objects at play in the example.

Actual curves are built and stored inside smart pointers; for instance, `depoSwapTermStructure` (the spot curve) is a `boost::shared_ptr<YieldTermStructure>`, and so is `bondDiscountingTermStructure`. They basically behave as pointers to `YieldTermStructure`.

Then, you have instances of `Handle<YieldTermStructure>` (or `RelinkableHandle`) which give you another level of indirection: a `Handle` contains a `shared_ptr` and can switch it for another if needed (the rationale for that and a few more details are available at [this link](http://implementingquantlib.com/2013/07/odds-and-ends-smart-pointers-and-handles.html)).

In the example, the `libor3m` index is passed the `liborTermStructure` handle, so it will forecast its fixings by using whatever curve is linked to it: in this case, `depoSwapTermStructure`, since the statement

```
liborTermStructure.linkTo(depoSwapTermStructure);
```

is executed before pricing the bond. As you say, the coupon rates are calculated by forecasting the index fixings off the curve and adding the spread. If we linked `liborTermStructure` to another curve and asked the bond for its cash flows again, they would be recalculated based on the new curve.

The same happens for discounting. Whatever curve is linked to `discountingTermStructure` will be used to discount the cash flows; in the example, that would be `bondDiscountingTermStructure`.

As for how the coupon rates are calculated: each coupon calculates its own rate and amount with the help of the `BlackIborCouponPricer` instance that is built right after the bond and associated to the coupons shortly afterwards by the statement

```
setCouponPricer(floatingRateBond.cashflows(),pricer);
```

The code that actually performs the calculation involves the `BlackIborCouponPricer` and `FloatingRateCoupon` classes (more details are [here](http://implementingquantlib.com/2014/01/chapter-4-part-1-of-5-cash-flows-and.html) and in the posts that follow) but ultimately the rate is calculated in the `IborIndex` class as:

```
Rate IborIndex::forecastFixing(const Date& fixingDate) const {
    Date d1 = valueDate(fixingDate);
    Date d2 = maturityDate(d1);
    Time t = dayCounter_.yearFraction(d1, d2);
    return forecastFixing(d1, d2, t);
}

Rate IborIndex::forecastFixing(const Date& d1,
                                      const Date& d2,
                                      Time t) const {
    DiscountFactor disc1 = termStructure_->discount(d1);
    DiscountFactor disc2 = termStructure_->discount(d2);
    return (disc1/disc2 - 1.0) / t;
}
```

Comment: I am confused. How is the `libor3m` forecasting its fixings,is it computing forward rates or is it looking for the spot rates associated to the cash flow dates and assigning it to that particular coupon rate and then adding the spread?                                          



If I want to compute the cash flows by estimating using forward rates, do I have to create a new `YieldTermStructure` of forward rates (call it `ForwardTermStructure`) and  a new `RelinkableHandle` for it or do I do it as in the bond.cpp example and assume that somewhere this forward rate calculation is done?

Comment: Oh, I see the source of the confusion. No, the coupons calculate forward rates based on the spot curve. I'll add some directions to the answer.